# LINQ Contains Match Exactly

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I'm trying to find matches for a set of criteria in a DataRow array.

```
string startDate = "1/1/2012";
string endDate = "11/1/2012";

DataRow[] scheduleResults = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Name").Contains("Eglin")
    && r.Field<string>("Name").Contains(startDate)
    && r.Field<string>("Name").Contains(endDate)).ToArray();
```

This returns me two DataRows in the `scheduleResults`

1. `USAF:Eglin (1/1/2012-11/1/2012)`
2. `USAF:Eglin (11/1/2012-3/31/2017)`

I can see that the `startDate` is actually contained in `endDate` which is why I'm getting those two results.  My question is, how to match on the entire `startDate` exactly, so I won't get that second result returned.

Comment: Is it correct that your data table contains a single column titled "Name" that contains the name, a job code, a start date, and an end date?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the database I'm pulling this info in from has just been set up with an ID field and a "Name" field and the convention that has been set up is to just included the relevant information like start/end dates into the "Name" field.  Definitely not ideal, but thats what I have to work with at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the format stays the same you can just match on `"(" + startDate + "-" + endDate + ")"`

```
string startDate = "1/1/2012";
string endDate = "11/1/2012";

DataRow[] scheduleResults = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Name").Contains("Eglin")
    && r.Field<string>("Name").Contains("(" + startDate + "-" + endDate + ")"))
    .ToArray();
```

This is assuming that all your data is in one field called "Name" and that wasn't a typo.  If possible it would be better to store the data elements in separate columns.

Comment: That would improperly match "USAF:Elgin (11/1/2012-11/1/2012)", I'd recommend making the second contains check `.Contains(String.Format("({0}-{1})",startDate,endDate))`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your data is fundamentally in an awkward format. You *could* format the exact match that you want, but it's still a pain.

I would suggest that you parse each row into a type containing all the constituent parts (organization, name, start, end?) using `DateTime` as the start/end values (or `LocalDate` if you choose to use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library...). At that point, it becomes much simpler to work with the data. The query would be something like:

```
var query = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(row => ParseRow)
                       .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Eglin") &&
                                   p.StartDate == startDate &&
                                   p.EndDate == endDate)
                       .ToList();
```

(Where `ParseRow` would be a method taking a `DataRow` and returning an appropriate type.)

If you're going to work with lots of the values, you might want to just convert your `DataTable` to an appropriate list to start with. You can always include the source `DataRow` in your type if you need to be able to get at those rows rather than just the data.

Comment: Looks like that the OP's data doesn't have any `StartDate` and `EndDate` fields, it's just `Name` of type string?

Comment: @KingKing: Having reread the question, I see what you mean. Deleting and editing.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Regex` for this is perfect:

```
string name = "Eglin";
DataRow[] scheduleResults = 
        myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => Regex.IsMatch(r.Field<string>("Name"),
                       string.Format(".*{0}.*{1}.*{2}", name, startDate, endDate)))
        .ToArray();
```